# Novel regarding undersea laboratory super brain that captures scientists

Tags: novel, story-identification

Finally they managed to tire it out and escape through the ventilation system.
I read it a long time ago and my memory is vague.

Comment: How long ago? Anything you can remember about the characters? Even the smallest detail could be helpful

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Movie where a crewman asks "Are we being tested?"](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/153992/movie-where-a-crewman-asks-are-we-being-tested)

Comment: @Otis A novel identification can't be a duplicate of movie identification, even if the movie is based on novel. By definition, the answers can not ever be the same work. Also, per our story-id dupe policy, OP on other question never indicated that *Sphere* was the correct answer anyway, so even if it _were_ about the novel, we couldn't dupe close without confirmation.

Comment: @CreationEdge, my apologies! I clearly wasn't paying enough attention to the details on this one.

Comment: @Otis Mainly want to prevent further close votes with my notice, no worries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a shot in the dark, but you're description vaguely reminds me of the novel *Sphere* by Michael Crichton.

In that novel scientists are at the bottom of the ocean and an alien artifact interacts with their minds to dramatic and tragic effect.